# Visual Studio Code debugging fortran Array

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran

I have a small issue when debugging Fortran with Visual Studio Code. I have allocate a big array which size is 83*82*36, I am able to stop at breakpoints and evaluate variables by hovering on them or adding them to watch. However when I attempt to view this array. I can only see those first 9.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What are you hovering over in your screenshot? Which array is that? What would you expect to see instead? Please be detailed and specific.

Comment: Soo... your end goal is to be able to see 838236 records in a popup hover window? Wouldn't you better use an expression on watch, or something?

Comment: on watch it also only show 9 items，my goal is to show all items on watch。

Comment: Firstly, that hover message looks like its from a matrix (9x...) as opposed to an array, that or you are missing your GDB pretty printers. As for your main question, how exactly would you expect 800k+ entries to be viewed? The performance of the Watch Window will be horrible, that's why VS Code caps the entries you can view to 1000. You will have to slice your arrays if you want to view them within VS Code. Otherwise just save them to a file and plot them.